# Postgres - how to create text search index with weighted vectors?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres doesn't to allow concatenating vectors in this fashion:

```
CREATE INDEX pgweb_idx ON pgweb USING
gin(
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', title),'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', body), 'B')
);
```

gives

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"`

It allows this syntax in a select or update statement.

Is there a way to create a weighted full text index without adding a `tvector` column to the table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't really offer a good explanation why it happens in this case however you can solve this problem by adding extra pair of parentheses around the expression

```
CREATE INDEX pgweb_idx ON pgweb USING
gin(
    (setweight(to_tsvector('english', title),'A') ||  setweight(to_tsvector('english', body), 'B'))
);
```

Comment: This is explained in the [CREATE INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) page of the docs: *The expression usually must be written with surrounding parentheses, as shown in the syntax. However, the parentheses can be omitted if the expression has the form of a function call.* (the expression-based index needs the parenthesis, the usual column-based does not need one)

Comment: @pozs Oh...Yeah, probably should have checked that page. Thank you.